# Creating views between two tables in SQL

Tags: sql

SQL isn't my strongest subject and I'm having struggles with creating views.

I am supposed to create a view which will indicate which timesheets are in dispute. These are timesheets that have not been approved and are older than two weeks old. Data should be displayed in the following format:

```
TIMESHEET_ID               TIMESHEET             EMPLOYEE
15                         16-feb-15             Gareth Smith
```

Again I haven't done SQL in some time. The tables needed for this create view are  as follows:

`timesheet`:

```
 Name                                      Null?    Type

 TIMESHEET_ID                              NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 TIMESHEET_EMP                             NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 TIMESHEET_WC                              NOT NULL DATE
 TIMESHEET_HOURS                                    NUMBER(2)
 TIMESHEET_OT                                       NUMBER(2)
 TIMESHEET_APPROVED                                 NUMBER(3)
```

`employee`:

```
Name                                      Null?    Type

EMP_ID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
EMP_FIRSTNAME                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(50)
EMP_SURNAME                                        VARCHAR2(50)
EMP_DEPARTMENT                                     NUMBER(2)
EMP_STREET                                         VARCHAR2(50)
EMP_TOWN                                           VARCHAR2(50)
EMP_DISTRICT                                       VARCHAR2(50)
EMP_GRADE                                          NUMBER(3)
EMP_SITE                                           VARCHAR2(30)
FUNTOM_GRADE                                       NUMBER(3)
EMPLOYEE_STATUS                                    VARCHAR2(10)
EMPLOYEE_START                                     DATE
EMPLOYEE_TERMINATION                               DATE
```

Comment: Step 1) do a simple select with a join. Step 2) add "two weeks old" condtition. Step 3) Use the query from step 2 in your create view statement.

Comment: You haven't asked a question here. Please edit the question to show us what you have tried and give us specifically what your problem is.

Comment: Additionally, it looks like you switched the employee and timesheet tables and have nothing to link the 2 tables on.

Comment: Hi @newbie, where is the `timesheet_id` in your `employee` table?

Comment: @AndyK, I guess the JOIN condition should be `timesheet.TIMESHEET_EMP = employee.EMP_ID`.

Comment: @jarlh , pretty good candidate actually

Answer (score 1):

Something like this.

Join the two tables using TIMESHEET_EMP = EMP_ID. Check that the date is at least 14 days old. Also verify TIMESHEET_APPROVED - but I don't know the values here - so replace ??? with your own value.

```
create view viewname as
select t.TIMESHEET_ID, t.TIMESHEET, e.EMPLOYEE
from timesheet t
  join employee e ON t.TIMESHEET_EMP = e.EMP_ID
where t.TIMESHEET_WC <= current_date - '14' day
  and t.TIMESHEET_APPROVED = ???
```

Since no dbms has been specified, I'm using ANSI SQL date comparison.